# Como mudar uma imagem utilizando o commandButton no Java PrimeFaces?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Boa tarde, estou desenvolvendo um jogo de batalha naval em JAVA utilizando o Primefaces pra fazer a front-end. Gostaria de uma ajuda pra montar um commandButton que ao ser clicado, acione uma função que ira retornar se a casa selecionada pelo usuario esta vazia ou se não, qual navio esta alocado ali e depois subtitua a imagem que tem nesse commandButton pela imagem do navio.

```
<h:commandButton image="/resources/images/agua.png" style="width:100%"/>
```

A maior dificuldade seria nessa troca de uma imagem por outra se alguém puder dar uma ajudinha :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você terá que usar o EL (Expression Language) do primefaces no frontend.

Provavelmente tu tem uma classe chamada `NavioBean` essa classe tem um atributo chamado `imagem` (ou `img`, seja qual for o nome)

```
<h:commandButton image="#{navioBean.imagem}" style="width:100%"/>
```